# jQuery make script wait until action is complete

Tags: jquery, callback, wait, appendto

is it possible to get jQuery to wait until this piece of code has done it's work?

```
if (hrefs[arrayCounter]) {
    $('<li>').append($('<img>', {
        src: hrefs[arrayCounter]
    }).css({
        "height": windowHeight
    })).appendTo(ul)
}​
```

Right after this the images scroll and I need the calculated width before I scroll. In other words, it's going too soon while the image is still loading. From what I know appendTo() won't take a callback so how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Before using this code, be warned that **there are several cross-browser issues with the onload event for images**. [They are described in the documentation for jQuery's `.load` method.](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/)

You need to build a Deferred object and pipe it based on the onload function of each image.

```
$.when.apply($,$.map(hrefs, function(href) {
    var imgLoad = $.Deferred(),
        $img = $('<img>').css('height',windowHeight);
    ul.append($('<li>').append($img));
    $img.load($.proxy(imgLoad.resolve,imgLoad));
    $img.attr('src',href);
    return imgLoad;
})).done(function(){
    // all images are loaded when this executes
})
```

This code uses `jQuery.map` to turn the array of hrefs into an array of Deferred objects. While looping and appending the images, each image gets its own Deferred object, whose `.resolve` method is bound to a `.load` handler on the image. When the image loads, the Deferred will resolve.

This array of Deferreds is applied as arguments to `jQuery.when`, which returns a Promise that resolves when all its arguments resolve--which in this case means that all the images have loaded! We then attach a `.done` callback to that Promise.

Answer (score 0):

I made [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mpzRs/) which basically sticks to the image's .load() event to fire the new code. This works only for [loadable content](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) but for what I understood seems to fit your needs.

Bascially you'll have to bind the code you want to be fired to the `.on('load',handler)` event of your image.

Hope this helps somehow.

Comment: Hi, how would that work with my situation - I have an element that triggers this code when it's clicked. It loads more images into a slider...